# Naive Recursive Algorithm for Polynomial Multiplication in Python

Tags: python, recursion, polynomial-math, polynomials

I am trying to implement the **divide-and-conquer algorithm for polynomial multiplication**. Here is the pseudocode given in the lecture notes:
[image]

where `A, B` are lists of coefficients of each polynomial, `n` is the size of the problem (degree - 1) and `a_l, b_l` are indices of the coefficients of interest.

Here is my attempt at implementing it using Python3:

```
def poly_mult_dc_naive(A, B, n, a, b):
  n = int(n)
  a = int(a)
  b = int(b)
  C = [None] * int(2*n - 1)

  if n == 1:
    C[0] = A[a] * B[b]
    return C[0]

  C[0:n-1] = poly_mult_dc_naive(A, B, n//2, a, b)
  C[n:2*n-1] = poly_mult_dc_naive(A, B, n//2, a + (n // 2), b + (n // 2))

  W = poly_mult_dc_naive(A, B, n/2, a, b + (n // 2))
  V = poly_mult_dc_naive(A, B, n/2, a + n/2, b)
  C[n // 2:n + (n // 2) - 1] += W + V
  return C
```

However I'm getting strange results. For example let `A = [1,2,3,4] B = [4,3,2,1]` I get:

`[4, None, 8, 3, 6, 12, None, 16, 9, 12, 2, None, 4, 1, 2, None, 8, 3, 4, None, None]`

Correct answer is `[4, 11, 20, 30, 20, 11, 4]`

Could someone please point out where I've gone wrong and how it could be done?

Comment: Just a tip about legibility, why not assume n,a,b are integers, since you're using `// 2` floor division. Make the caller responsible for passing integer arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Quick update: I think I've managed to debug my code my using a numpy array for C instead of a list. Here is the updated version:

```
import numpy as np

def poly_mult_dc_naive(A, B, n: int, a: int, b: int):
  C = np.zeros(2*n - 1, dtype=int) # here I changed it from list to np array
  if n == 1:
    C[0] = A[a] * B[b]
    return C[0]
  C[0:n-1] = poly_mult_dc_naive(A, B, n//2, a, b)
  C[n:2*n-1] = poly_mult_dc_naive(A, B, n//2, a + (n // 2), b + (n // 2))
  W = poly_mult_dc_naive(A, B, n//2, a, b + (n // 2))
  V = poly_mult_dc_naive(A, B, n/2, a + (n//2), b)
  C[(n // 2) : (3*n // 2) - 1] += W + V
  return C
```

BONUS QUESTION: Does anyone know of a better way I could keep the arguments n, a, and b as int types?

I just feel like having to write:

```
n = int(n)
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
```

might not be the most elegant way.

Comment: Tell us what was the bug?

Comment: I  don't see that you need to coerce n,a,b from float to int, just use `// 2` rounding division everywhere (i.e. in the W,V lines), it keeps ints as int. If you have a counterexample which goes wrong, show us.

Comment: Also, the line `C[n // 2:n + (n // 2) - 1]` badly needs parenthesizing, it misreads very easily. I'd write `C[(n//2) : (3*n//2)-1]`

Comment: 1. So the bug was that using a list for C (i.e. the result coefficients) leads to issues when assigning values to slices of it. So it would instead append values instead of assiging them. Changing the list to a numpy array seems to have fixed it.

Comment: 2. You're right! Thank you! I tried that at first but I still got an error, but it turned out I missed doing // instead of / for a couple of lines. 
3. I've parenthesized the line as suggested. Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: Also for clarity, you don't need to initialize or compute `C[]` in the base-case (n==1), just directly `return A[a] * B[b]` (assuming that's correct). And strictly you don't need to initialize `C[]` ever, it's directly computed. So that eliminates two more lines.

Answer (score 0):

- There should be no need to coerce `n,a,b` from float to int. Just use `// 2` integer division everywhere (i.e. in the W,V lines). That will "keep" ints as ints.
- The line `C[n // 2:n + (n // 2) - 1]` badly needs parenthesizing, it misreads very easily. I'd write `C[(n//2) : (3*n//2)-1]`
- But I seriously recommend you use numpy vectors, not Python lists. Adding, multiplying etc. are vectorized.